# Как сделать редирект при неправильном порядке аргументов в url?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, django

Есть часть регулярного выражения `((-(?P<some_arg>[\w/]+)))*`, где аргументы выстраиваются в цепочку, разделенную при помощи символа `-`.

В CBV я принимаю эти аргументы:

```
self.kwargs.get('some_arg', None)
```

Разделяю их, и делаю запрос в БД, в котором передаю список аргументов

`...filter(args__in=[agrs_list])...` , но порядок аргументов в списке не мграет роли

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне сохранить порядок аргументов в соответствии с id этих элементов в БД. по возрастанию. И если порядок нарушается, то сделать редирект на правильный порядок.

То есть, есть в адресную строку вбиваю: `id3-id1-id4-id5-id2`, то отобразиться должно `id1-id2-id3-id4-id5`

Вообще нету никаких идей, как бы это можно было реализовать.

Comment: сделать sorted при запросе в базу?

Comment: @AndrioSkur, а как избежать попадания на урл при не правильном порядке ?

Comment: Приведите примеры запросов и того что вы хотите получить в итоге.( А то я щас не очень хорошо понимаю порядок id.)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, задача не в запроса сохранить порядок аргументов ( это ни на что не повиляет), а в урле.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Выполнить запрос без упорядочивания аргументов.
2. Из запроса достать ID.
3. Сложить в массив и отсортировать.
4. Сравнить сортированный и не сортированный массивы.
5. Делаем редирект.
6. Выполняем новый запрос.

Или в урле прямо так и написанно id1-id2....?

Comment: Нет, это для примера. 
Да, ваше решение - то, что нужно.
А как сделать редирект на нужный порядок, ведь это kwargs, а словарь - не упорядоченный объект.

Comment: урл очень странный. его наверное проще собрать руками и послать редирект через HttpResponseRedirect

Comment: чем странный?
Я показал только кусок выражения. Руками собрать не получится, потому что одинаковых частей в урле может быть сколько угодно.

Comment: `"-".join(array_of_slugs)`

Comment: а это к чему?
Задача заключалась в том, чтобы принять аргументы в одной единственной последовательности, и если они приходят не в этой последовательности, то сделать редирект на такой же урл, но с правильной последовательностью аргументов.